# Php least number

Tags: php, html

can any one help me about how to find the least number of five inputs like 1,2,3,4,5
where the least is 1...

and find the 2nd least number where it is 2
then 3rd least number where it is 3
and 4th least numb where it is 4
and the largest number where it is 5..

```
<input type ="text" name ="num1">
<input type ="text" name ="num2">
<input type ="text" name ="num3">
<input type ="text" name ="num4">

<input type ="text" name ="answer">
```

Comment: yup it is.. and i dont know how to do it..can you help me

Comment: You need to show some more effort before we could help you.

Answer (score 4):

You would `sort()` the numbers and then echo them back into the `value` attribute of your `answer` element.

Comment: @SpitFirez: I won't give you the entire code. Some work is required on your behalf. Especially since this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array($_POST["num1"],$_POST["num2"],$_POST["num3"],$_POST["num4"]);
sort($values);
var_dump($values);
```

Comment: how can i find the 2nd least number here sir?? where it is num2? or find the 3rd least number where it is num3??

Comment: if u want to know which is which then using `asort($values)` is better cause it maintain the index [function.asort.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)